# Not able to create an Android app using scringo

Tags: android, scringo

I am trying to create new Android app using scringo by following this link,

```
    http://www.scringo.com/docs/android-guides/quickstart/

finally after completing all the step when i tried to run my app its telling

    "Your project contains errors.please fix them before running".
```

when i saw in problems view its showing the following errors
1.Project 'Scringo' is missing required source folder: 'gen'    Scringo     Build path  Build Path Problem

2.The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\v Drive\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\workspace\Scringo\bin\scringo.jar'    Chat        Build path  Build Path Problem

i followed all the steps correctly, why these errors are showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the scringo dependency in build path, restart the eclipse and again add the scringo project as dependency from 'configur build path'